# Command wont run in script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am trying to run a command in a shell script but it is not working.

Out side of the script in the shell I can run the following command on the needed host. The file is created with the correct information inside.

```
sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d > /tmp/expirelist.txt
```

When the command is run in my script I first ssh over then run the command but I get the following error.

```
[batch@testserver01 bin]$ checkP.sh
Testserver02
/usr/local/bin/checkP.sh: line 7: /tmp/expirelist.txt: Permission denied
```

Here is a part of the script. I have tried using `ssh -o`

```
#!/bin/bash

for SERVER in `cat /admin/lists/testlist`
do
  echo $SERVER

  ssh $SERVER sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d > /tmp/expirelist.txt
...
```

What is causing the Permission denied error?

Comment: What are the permissions of that file on the local machine?

Comment: Buy running the command it will create the file with
`-rw-rw-r--. 1 batch   batch    23 Jan  6 14:01 expirelist.txt`

Comment: @p0ot, but if the file was already created in `/tmp` by a different user, say while you were testing the command earlier, that would explain your error.

Comment: BTW, do you want the `cut` and redirection to happen on the local machine or the remote machine? If it's the latter, you need more quotes to force them into the `ssh` command's arguments.

Comment: By the way -- I wonder if you might find `getent shadow` interesting; unlike directly running `cat /etc/shadow`, it works with systems configured to use alternate directory sources -- NIS, LDAP, etc etc -- and can also retrieve only the specific accounts you care about (which, with many backends, can be more efficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use hardcoded temporary filenames -- when you do, it means that if one user (say, your development account) already ran this script and left a file named `/tmp/expirelist.txt` behind, no other user can run the same script.

```
tempfile=$(mktemp -t expirelist.XXXXXX)
ssh "$SERVER" sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d >"$tempfile"
```

By using `mktemp`, you guarantee that each invocation will use a new, distinct, and previously-nonexisting temporary file, preventing any chance of conflict.

---

By the way -- if you want the file to be created on the remote system rather than the local system, you'd want to do this instead:

```
ssh "$SERVER" <<'EOF'
tempfile=$(mktemp -t expirelist.XXXXXX)
sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d >"$tempfile"
EOF
```

Comment: Creating the tempfile did the trick!

The EOF part is also very useful I wish I could upvote more.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about this, but you could be running into an issue with having the 'sudo' within your script. You could try removing the 'sudo' from the script, and running it like this:

```
$ sudo checkP.sh
```

Comment: Negative; the `sudo` only applies to the `cat` stage, not to the entire pipeline. It can't change the permissions for the `>/tmp/expirelist`, which is done via pipeline setup _before_ `sudo` (or any other pipeline component) is even started.